# Spring Boot 2.x App in production: Overridden text resource files should take immediate effect (after page reload)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, production

The scenario is as follows:

The app has stuff like grid column headers, form labels, etc. extracted into text resource files. Users should be able to override these via a separate file.

For example, if there is something like `form.user.lastName="Last name"` in the main file, users should be able to override the same (in this other place available through their profile) as `form.user.lastName="Family name"`.

If this all happens in production, would it be necessary to recompile and re-deploy the app? Is there a way to enable it without recompilation/redeployment (so that page refresh is enough)?

Comment: are you using Spring cloud config server? If yes then look at refresh scope.

Comment: No, but this could be the solution to what I need. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Two option which I can think of

1. Spring cloud config server with a refresh scope
2. Store the value in the database and read it from the database. Provide a rest endpoint to update the value in the database and refresh the value.